# Как изменить заливку круга на основе цвета фона с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

В основном я хочу, чтобы круг менял цвет, когда ползунок перемещает его по флагу: зеленый на белом фоне, белый на зеленом прямоугольнике.

```js
function move() {
  let slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
  let circle = document.querySelector("#player");
  circle.setAttribute("cx", slider.value);
}
```

```html
<h1>Flag</h1>
<svg width="375" height="375">
  <g id="flag">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="125" height="375" fill="green"/>
    <rect x="250" y="0" width="125" height="375" fill="green"/>
  </g>
  <circle id="player" cx="187.5" cy="187.5" r="10" fill="green" />
</svg><br>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="375" value="150" style="width:370px" oninput="move()">
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [how to change circle fill based on background color with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69457880/7394871) от участника  [@thegoldmolar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17038030/thegoldmolar).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69457880/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такой простой задачи можно использовать SVG-фильтр, а конкретно - `<feComposite>` со значением `xor`. Чтобы всё сработало, нужно понимать алгоритм действия фильтров, а он, примерно, таков:

- В памяти вычисляются слои с фигурами, заливками и т.п.;
- Слои растрируются с помощью `<feImage>`;
- К растрированным слоям применяется нужный фильтр;
- Итог рендерится (выводится на экран).

```js
function move() {
  let slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
  let circle = document.querySelector("#player");
  circle.setAttribute("cx", slider.value);
}
```

```html
<h1>Flag</h1>
<svg width="375" height="375" viewBox="-37.5 -37.5 375 375">
  <defs>
    <g id="flag">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="125" height="375" fill="green" />
      <rect x="250" y="0" width="125" height="375" fill="green" />
    </g>
    <circle id="player" cx="187.5" cy="187.5" r="10" fill="green" />
    <filter id="imageXor">
      <feImage xlink:href="#flag" result="lay1" />
      <feImage xlink:href="#player" result="lay2" />
      <feComposite operator="xor" in="lay1" in2="lay2" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#flag" filter="url(#imageXor)"></use>
</svg>
<br>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="375" value="187.5" style="width:370px" oninput="move()">
```

Таким образом, необходимо помнить, что очень многие фильтры работают именно с растром. Часто про это забывают и пытаются напрямую использовать векторный (читай, параметрический) объект с растровым (в случае с картинками и градиентами) или таким же вектором.

Comment: ценный ответ. Всё просто и красиво, показывая мощь фильтров SVG. Благодарю Юра за ответ.

Comment: @Leonid  у меня, здесь в лесу  в Chrome Win7 всё работает, как часы. Приеду в город проверю на win10

Comment: @Leonid: в Chrome и Edge всё норм. В FF, да, беда...

Answer (score 3):

Нет простого способа сделать это с помощью SVG-фильтров или режимов наложения и т.д. Вам, вероятно, придется просто переключить цвет самостоятельно в зависимости от позиции круга. См. ниже.

```js
function move() {
  let slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
  let circle = document.querySelector("#player");
  circle.setAttribute("cx", slider.value);
  circle.setAttribute('fill', (slider.value >= 125 && slider.value < 250) ? 'green' : 'white');
}
```

```html
<h1>Flag</h1>
<svg width="375" height="375">
  <g id="flag">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="125" height="375" fill="green"/>
    <rect x="250" y="0" width="125" height="375" fill="green"/>
  </g>
  <circle id="player" cx="187.5" cy="187.5" r="10" fill="green"/>
</svg><br>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="375" value="150" style="width:370px" oninput="move()">
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69481492/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: Интересно, а вот получится ли сделать так, чтобы на переходе между зеленым и белым кружок окрашивался частично, соразмерно "залезанию" на другое поле. Сложно выразился. Можно ли кружок окрасить в два цвета, инвертируя цвета на границе двух областей. Может градиентом, сдвигая переход одного цвета в другой?

Comment: @Leonid наверное можно сделать, попробуй. Кружок сделай немного побольше для большего эффекта и попробуй сделать это на svg + css/ На canvas я уверен, что сделаешь. Но ты же хотел изучать SVG?

Comment: Я не отделяю SVG и CSS от JS и canvas. В любом случае мы имеем дело с браузерными API, просто JS дает большую свободу, что и хорошо и плохо)) Вот здесь в ответе использован JS, но размеры жестко зашиты. Они не ищет границы, он их тупо указывает. В итоге у нас одни и те же значения указаны и в SVG и в JS. А это недопустимо по идее. Источник должен быть строго один. И именно это смущает в SVG - отсутствие возможности повторять значения - вводить переменные. То есть, логика все равно должна быть в JS, а куда выводить ее уже не важно, что в canvas, что в SVG.

Comment: @Leonid  `а куда выводить ее уже не важно, что в canvas, что в SVG.`  ну так выведи в SVG :-) мне просто интересен SVG

Comment: Я подумаю над этой проблемой. Есть ощущение, что можно очень просто и элегантно все обыграть. Просто указывать значения X, при которых будет меняться градиент не интересно. Я подумаю))

Comment: Случайно минус нажал, исправил сразу, полезный вопрос

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, примите мои поздравления по достижению 100K!!! Мощный ответ UModel мне не переплюнуть и стараться не буду)) Пойду лучше отмечу эту важную веху в вашей карьере!!!

Comment: @Leonid Спасибо Леонид. Действительно очень приятно. Цифры ничто не значат , сегодня они есть, завтра их нет, приятен сам факт внимания и чувствую  твою искренность. Благодарю ещё раз!